# Using JDBC for a basic login system

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to create a project in java that registers and "Logs in" a user, however I have gotten the Registration part working correctly, I'm not sure how to go about returning the true/false for this. I have the query that needs to be used

```
public String login(String username, String password) {
    return "SELECT * WHERE Username=\""+username+"\" and Password=\""+password+"\";";
}
```

although, I'm just not sure what I'm doing, exactly. Any help?

I know how to write to the database, just not how to read from it.

Comment: Insider your method you need to actually *run* the SQL in order to get a result. Additionally: string literals need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL, not double quotes. And what's even more important: your code is wide open to SQL injection if you build your query like that.

Comment: I would recommend you use Spring Framework's JDBCTemplate: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: Spring's JDBC Template is good, but I think it's important to learn JDBC first, before using frameworks based upon it.

Answer (score 2):

Although Rahul Tripathi's answer would work, it exposes your application to SQL injection attack, meaning that I could damage your application by entering something like

```
'; drop table mytable;
```

in the username field. Since the user name is concatenated with the rest of the SQL, this is what would be executed:

```
SELECT * from mytable WHERE username=''; drop table mytable;
```

This is clearly not what you want!

Instead, use parameters and Prepared Statements:

```
String username = //get entered username from somewhere
String password = //get entered password from somewhere
Connection connection = //get database connection

String sqlString = "SELECT * from mytable WHERE username=? and password=?";

PreparedStatement login = connection.prepareStatement(sqlString);
login.setString(1, username);
login.setString(2, password);
ResultSet rs = login.executeQuery();
```

This is not a complete solution, you'll need to handle exceptions and process the ResultSet...

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you are asking but you can try like this:-

```
  sql = "SELECT * from mytable WHERE username='" + username + "' and password='"password"'";                                  
   rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   if( rs.next()){
        return true;
   } else {
       return false;
   }
```

You are also missing the `from` clause in your `select` statement.

**NOTE:-**

The above solution is very prone to SQL Injection. Instead try to use Prepared statement to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: Or drop the `if-else` and just simply: `return rs.next()`

Comment: @NickJ:- Yes thats correct. I was not clear to the OP's question. Anyways updated my answer!

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi  what would be the SQL syntax when i need to login using only password